# Executing tasklist on Windows with popen in C without cmd.exe popup

Tags: c, popen, tasklist

Hello everybody and **thanks** for your time.

I'm developing some kind of monitoring application in C and I fell in need of getting the current tasks list. So I'm using tasklist and getting the output thanks to popen();

```
ptr = popen("tasklist /V", "r");
while(1)
{
    if(fgets(temp, 255, ptr) == NULL) break;
    fputs(temp, log);
}
```

The problem is that for some fractions of a second a cmd.exe window pops up and that's really disturbing, because it switches focus on that new window and it makes my application go to windowed-mode instead of fullscreen.

So, I've spent days looking on either popen ways or Windows itself ones to start that process in an 'hidden' mode/window but got no result.
Things I already tried include:

```
cmd.exe /c tasklist /V
start /b cmd.exe /c tasklist /V
start /min /b cmd.exe /c tasklist /V
start /min cmd.exe /c tasklist /V
tasklist > somefile
```

I tried last one too so I would read the output from that *somefile* but seems like tasklist forces output to stdout since no data is written though file is created.

Hope in your answer and thank you anyway.

Comment: If your approach is to do text processing on the output of admin commands, maybe you should be working in a scripting language with good process control and text manipulation. C is not a very suitable tool for writing glue code to coordinate other programs that do most of the work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by calling [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28VS.85%29.aspx) passing `SW_HIDE` as the `wShowWindow` field of the [`STARTUPINFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686331%28VS.85%29.aspx) struct and including `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` in `dwCreationFlags`.

This method is a little brittle because you may find your app running on a machine with a version of `tasklist` that has a different output format.

If you want a list of all processes that are running you can call [`EnumProcesses`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682629%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I'm not yet that good with C and got some problems understanding how it should be used. Would you be so kind of giving me a brief example? I'd really appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: @Markku Why don't you try first yourself. Do a websearch, read the MSDN documentation, find some code samples. When you get stuck you can post another question here, with your code. A very high level overview is that you create the process. This results in a process handle being created. You then wait on that handle (WaitUntilSignaled). Once it is signaled that means the process is done and you can close the process. You also need to create a stdout file handle in which to capture the output. You'd be better off calling EnumProcesses though.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I solved it. I'll now post the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Task can be easily achieved using [EnumProcesses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682629%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Intuitive example given [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682623%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).